# Expect Script continues execute after ping response

Tags: expect, telnet

Hello i want To Make A script to test ping after ping success will continues execute comand. Thanks For All Your Helps

below my code

```
set ip [10.10.10.1,10.10.10.2]
foreach hostname $ip {
    spawn ping -c 2 -i 3 -W 1 $hostname
    expect { "0%" {
            spawn telnet $hostname
            expect "*sername:"
            send "$userper\n"
            expect "*assword:"
            send "$passper\n"
            expect "#"
            send "exit\n"
            expect eof
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify the platform and scripting language? `telnet` is not sufficient information, you need to say *what* program you are connecting to.

Comment: This is expect script, in this case i would verify succes ling amd continues execute my command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this `set ip [10.10.10.1,10.10.10.2]` will most likely give you `invalid command name "10.10.10.1,10.10.10.2"`

To make a list, use `set ip {10.10.10.1 10.10.10.2}` -- braces and spaces.

Next, that ping command does not require any interactivity, so don't spawn it, just `exec` it:

```
set ping_output [exec ping -c 2 -i 3 -W 1 $hostname]
```

And then check the output for `0%` -- note, you don't want to match `100%` so add a leading space to the pattern:

```
if {[regexp { 0%} $ping_output]} {
    spawn telnet $hostname
    ...
}
```

[expect](/questions/tagged/expect) is an extension of [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl) so [all the Tcl commands](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm) are at your disposal

Comment: Hi Glenn,  Thanks for your answer. I will try as your mantion. And will be update son.

Comment: Hi Glen your code is use full now my code running. but the next problem cause i using foreach, if the ip int the ip list time out  the code will be interact and automatic close the session.